# beautifulsoup scraping a href titles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to scrape titles inside a-href with BeautifulSoup.
actually, my code isn't working properly.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
name = 'Flow'
namec = 'Flow'
url = 'http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/' + name
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
main_text = soup.find('div', class_='mw-content-ltr mw-content-text')
ada = main_text.find_all('a', title=True)
```

page is http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Flow

i need to extract data from div class pi-data-value pi-font like this:

```
Missions:
Survival (DS3, T3)
Excavation (T3)
Enemies:
Arid Butcher 0.03%
Bailiff 0.03%
Bailiff Defector 0.03%
Butcher 0.03%
Drahk Master 0.03%
Drekar Manic 0.03%
Frontier Bailiff 0.03%
Frontier Butcher 0.03%
Grineer Manic 0.22%
Hyekka Master 0.03%
Infested Chroma 0.6%
Infested Mesa 0.6%
Kuva Butcher 0.03%
Kuva Drahk Master 0.03%
Kuva Hyekka Master 0.03%
Tenno Specter 0.6%
Tusk Butcher 0.03%
Other:
Orokin Tower Containers
```

Comment: Try `main_text = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mw-content-ltr mw-content-text'})`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete solution what you are looking for but it can get you started

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Flow")
content = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
main_div = content.find_all('div', {'class': ["pi-data-value", "pi-font"]})[3]
child_tags = main_div.findChildren()
for child in child_tags:
      print(child.text)
```

format the text according to your need

Comment: thanks! what the [3] stands for in your code? anyway it works flawlessly!

Comment: There are multiple div tags with the same class name, the one you want is the 3rd one.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
name = 'Flow'
namec = 'Flow'
url = 'http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/' + name
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
main_text = soup.find('div', id='mw-content-text').find_all('div', class_='pi-data-value pi-font')
for d in main_text:
    if d.find_next(string=True) == 'Missions:':
        snippets = str(d).split("<br/>")
        for snippet in snippets:
            snippet_soup = BeautifulSoup(snippet, 'html.parser')
            print(snippet_soup.text)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works without problems. What should i change, if i want to scrap another page in wikia? because it doesn't not work for everything there